# VGG13 pretrained ImageNet weights

Tags: keras, vgg-net

i'm trying to implement the VGG13 model in keras but i'm having a lot of difficulties in finding the ImageNet pretrained weights for it. Does anyone know where to find does?

Comment: I could not find weights for a Keras model, however, if you would like to use Pytorch check out: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/vgg.py

Comment: @JamesKl thanks for the answer but I specifically need those imagenet pretrained weights

Answer (score 1):

VGG13 is kinda of simple architecture so easy to implmeent using keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

#Number of label classes 

num_classes = 2

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
                 kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: I already tried looking there but i couldn't find any VGG13 model or weights for it. I need to implement the VGG13 model without the FC layers so re-wrote it by hand. I just needs weights for it and I can't find them anywhere (I only found does for VGG16 and VGG19). Btw i'm new to keras and neural networks so I'm sorry if I can't find them quickly cause I just don't know what and where to search

Comment: Ah sorry i missread VGG version VGG13 is way too simple architecture ill edit my post

Comment: thanks for the model, that's basically how i've done it, but still, I need specifically those imagenet pretrained weights. I was able to find them for VGG16 and VGG19 but not for VGG13...

Comment: i did some resreach online and checked tensorflow hub but i realy cant find pretrained version for vgg13 on image net, all starts with vgg13, you can train if if your have the computation and patience but i would suggest you to swap to later version

Comment: ok, I'll try that. Thank you for the answers!